# Windows 8.1 - How to delete an apps shortcut?

Tags: windows-8

I can't find the answer anywhere online.

I have a program I wrote in VS, installed it, and it put a tile in the apps start screen.

Now I want to delete it. Not uninstall the program, I just want to delete the tile in the apps (so nobody will see it there).

How can I do this? Where is the directory for these shortcuts?

Thanks,
Jason

Answer (score 0):

To remove it from the Start screen, right click on program's tile then on the bottom menu click 'Unpin from start' and it should be removed.

[image: Unpin]

To delete it from All Programs, find it in the All Apps section of the Start screen (type it's name while in full screen Start - search should start by itself), then right click it and select Open File Location. The Start Menu folder will open in Windows Explorer where you can add and delete any desired entries.

[image: Open File Location]